# Extracting txt file data using php

Tags: php, text

I have been able to extract data from a txt file using php and display in a browser. But, even after trying a lot, I have not been able to get it to display in the manner that I want. Each section of data is delimited by a semi-colon. I am providing sample of the txt file, php codes used and the output that I require - output in HTML in two columns. Can anybody help?

Input txt file :

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five;
Six
Seven
Eight
Nine
Ten;
```

Php code used :

```
function explodeRows($data) 
{
  $rowsArr = explode(";", $data);
  return $rowsArr;
}


function explodeLines($singleLine) 
{
  $linesArr = explode("\n", $singleLine);
  return $linesArr;
}


$filename = "sample.txt";
$handle   = fopen($filename, 'r');
$data     = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$rowsArr  = explodeRows($data);


for($i=0;$i<count($rowsArr);$i++) 
{
  $lineDetails = explodeRows($rowsArr[$i]);
  echo  "<td>"  . $lineDetails[0] . "</td>";
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Output from above code :

```
One Two Three Four Five
Six Seven Eight Nine Ten
```

Output from var_dump($rowsArr); :

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(27) "One Two Three Four Five" [1]=> string(30) " Six Seven Eight Nine Ten" [2]=> string(2) " " }
array(3) { [0]=> string(27) "One Two Three Four Five" [1]=> string(30) " Six Seven Eight Nine Ten" [2]=> string(2) " " }
array(3) { [0]=> string(27) "One Two Three Four Five" [1]=> string(30) " Six Seven Eight Nine Ten" [2]=> string(2) " " }
```

Output Required :

```
One     Two               Six     Seven
Three                     Eight
Four    Five              Nine    Ten
```

Comment: Show us the output you getting using above code.

Comment: Should the second call to `explodeRows` (inside the `for` loop) be `explodeLines` instead?

Comment: You've called `explodeRows()` twice but not `explodeLines()`... I'm not sure if this was a copy paste error when bringing the code into [so] or not...

Comment: @Rikesh - Output that I get using the above code is in a single line till the delimiter i.e. till the semi-colon that is One to Five on one line and Six to Ten on another.

Comment: @Mark Parnell - Do you mean to say that  `explodeRows($rowsArr[$i])`  should be `explodeLines($linesArr[$i])` ? If yes, then, tried that earlier. Didn't help.

Comment: @Lix - Where? In which section? Where shall I put the `explodeLines()` again?

Comment: @CodeCruncher - Can you show us the output of `var_dump($rowsArr);` ?

Comment: @cod - in the final loop where you define `$lineDetails`.

Comment: @Lix - Just tried that i.e. `lineDetails = exploedLines($linesArr[$i]);`. But, getting an `Undefined Variable : linesArr` error.

Comment: @cod - I'm sorry, but you're going to have to do some of the work yourself. We're not going to debug the entire application for you. Look at the line you put... How can you execute an explode function on a variable that hasn't been initialized yet? You are defining `lineDetails` as a result of the explode so you can't use it inside the explode...

Comment: @Lix - My codes were already provided before you suggested the solution. I tried your solution and let you know what output it gave. I just sought help after trying to solve it for 2 days. Anyhow, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Lix - If you were referring to **exploedLines**, then I would like to tell you that it is a typo in typing over here. But, not in the actual code. As I have told @Mark above, I have tried several different combinations & permutations of the code, even having another `for loop` with `lineDetails = explodeLines($linesArr[$x]);` along with `explodeRows(...)`. But, as nothing helped, I sought help over here.

Comment: Use `<p>` (paragraph) instead of `<td>` (table cell), as no `<table><tr>`.